# MOSS -List Items to large 10k+

Tags: 2007

MOSS- I have a list with 10k+ Items and when users click on the List it takes forever to Load.The List has more than 10K items ins it dated from 2010 till current date. In that List is there any way i can limit it to load less items, Can i make it to load items dated from 2013.

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create filtered and paginated views as well as putting indexes on columns.

So in your example for 2013, you could create a calculated column that returned the year based on the created date, then filter the list where that calculated column equals 2013, sort it descending and page the results to maybe 500 at a time.

You should see a performance increase.

Comment: Thanks for helping , i basically created a different view and sorted it to Created date(Column) equal to 2013 and it loads items for 2013 and return results more quickly

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to split the one list into multiple lists. If you can't do that then you should look at moving the items into folders in the list (perhaps a folder for each year).

See [Manage lists and libraries with many items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010173667.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for helping , i basically created a different view and sorted it to Created date(Column) equal to 2013 and it loads items for 2013 and return results more quickly